# MySQL: Using COUNT function inside a SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, count

I am fairly new to MySQL queries, especially more complex ones.
I have two tables that I want to join together (x and y).  Table x contains Name, ID and TotalNum where y contains ID and Online.  So it looks like this:

### Table X

```
Name  | Store| TotalNum 
Blah  | 1    | 3 
Blah1 | 2    | 2 Etc..
```

### Table Y

```
Store| Lane  | Online 
1    | 1     | 1 
1    | 2     | 1 
1    | 3     | 0 
2    | 1     | 1 
2    | 2     | 0 
Etc..
```

I am trying to join my tables together and return a count where Online = 1
So, the result I am after is:

```
Name  | TotalNum | Online
Blah  | 3        | 2
Blah1 | 2        | 1
Etc..
```

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.TotalNum, COUNT(r.Online = 1) AS Online FROM TableX AS r
LEFT JOIN TableY AS s ON s.Store = r.Store
WHERE r.Store = 'xx'
```

But it just returns a count of the total rows regardless if Online = 1 or 0.
Any help appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT x.Name, x.TotalNum, SUM(y.Online = 1) Online FROM TableX x
LEFT JOIN TableY y ON x.Store = y.Store
WHERE x.Store = 'xx'
```

If you also want a `0` if there is no matching element in the `TableY` then you should do `COALESCE` the results: `COALESCE(SUM(y.Online = 1))`.

Additionally, it is no clear what you mean by `ID` as I don't see any on the query nor in the tables. However, this query works in the bases that you can only one distinct `name` and `TotalNum` for a single `Store`.

Comment: Damn, that simple hey! I did try the SUM function, but had my query muddled up.  Thanks heaps for the speedy reply.  Also, for the record, ID was meant to be STORE sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 1):

It's just a matter of summing `online`!

```
SELECT
    s.Name,
    s.TotalNum,
    sum(r.Online) AS Online
FROM TableX AS r
LEFT JOIN TableY AS s ON s.Store = r.Store
WHERE r.Store = 'xx'
```

Answer (score 1):

This method using count also worked for me:

```
SELECT tablex.name, tablex.storeID, tablex.totalNum, count(online) FROM tablex
INNER JOIN tabley
ON tablex.storeID = tabley.storeID
WHERE online = 1
GROUP BY name
```

My result

```
name    storeID     totalNum    count(online)
blaA    1           3           2
blaB    2           2           1
```